# Ionic template not refreshed properly with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

For example:

I Listed out the Task which are going to done.when i close the particular task and redirect by using $state.go() to the list out page is not refreshed properly when i using Ctrl+F5 in browser only it will get refreshed .Thanks in advance

```
$scope.data_send_data = {};
var current_userid = window.localStorage['session_userid'];
data_send_data = {
  current_user: current_userid
};
$http.post(Config.AppUrl + "/Tasks/get_asstasklist", data_send_data).success(function(response) {
  $scope.tasks = response;
});
```

For closing task:

```
$scope.close_task = function(data_id)
        {

            $scope.data_send_data   ={};
            data_send_data= {id:data_id,status:'Closed'};
            $http.post(Config.AppUrl+"/Tasks/task_status_change",data_send_data)
            .success(function(response) {
                if(response.status==='Closed')
                {
                   alert('Task has been Successfully Closed');
                   $window.location.reload(true);
                   $state.go('app.assignedtasks');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can we see your complete code? This is missing any reference to `$scope`.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: please don't post unformatted code in comments, edit your question to add the extra detail instead.

Comment: Why do you use post to get list of task. Use the get and send the current user id as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the lost of services when you come to the **app.assignedtasks** then your closing task route state should not be a substate of the the assignedtasks.

Eg : if you *closing task route state* is like **app.assignedtasks.closetask** then from there if you use **state.go('app.assignedtasks')** will  not initialized the controller. Hence it will not load the assigned tasks.

You need to have the state as **app.closetask** in your router and this will resolve the issue for when you go back to **app.assignedtasks**.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use the `$window` instead of `window` in angular or better still [$localStorage](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage) as in this scenerio

If I understand right, You want to persist the tasks json data in the so that when you change your view or refresh the page, the data state is not lost(as in it is retrieved from the `$localStorage` or api and updates the scope variable which displays the tasks.

A Solution I have to this are as follows,

- Use the `$rootScope` variable to store the tasks you instead of `$scope`(I would advice you to attach it to the `$rootScope` instead, as in `$rootScope.tasks = response` instead of `$scope.tasks = response` . This is because the `$rootScope` variable is available in all views because it is a parent to the $scope variable.
- You can then watch the tasks variable and update it in the `localStorage` automatically when changes occur

  ```
  yourApp.run(function($localStorage){ 
      if($sessionStorage.tasks !== undefined){
          $rootScope.tasks = $localStorate.tks; 
      }else{
          $rootScope.tasks = {};
      }
      $rootScope.$watch('tasks',function(newValue,oldValue){
          $localStorage.userTasks = $rootScope.tasks; 
      },true);

  });
  ```

*You can do the same for the user ID*

**

> Doing this enables you to store the value of the updated tasks in the
>   localStorage variable, and automatically update its value when the
>   value changes in scope(close_task function),
>
> Putting the snippet in your run function
>   enables it to retrieve and set the tasks from the `localStorage` to
>   the `rootScope` and therefore `$scope`

*You can also use sessionStorage*

Hope this helps